# Want to rollup related content using metadata

Tags: metadata, content, intranet

I was thinking that using enterprise search and metadata to rollup related content would be a good solution to improve efficiency in my company's intranet.

Let's say, I need to fill out a purchase request for office goods. Now, I would have to look for the instructions which lay somewhere in the intranet and then, go to somewhere else to find out the necessary forms so I can do the request. Takes unnecessary time, indeed.
But let's say I could just go to my advanced search page and just input something like "purchase request" and get all the related content from different locations in my intranet.

My question is, would that be a viable or good idea?

If yes, how could I implement the search query and metadata in order to achieve this? Any ideas would be of great help! Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a managed metadata set through a couple of methods - see here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-managed-metadata-column-c2a06717-8105-4aea-890d-3082853ab7b7

Once this is done, you'll need to create a result source to look for the specific meta-data that you've created.

Site Settings > Manage Result Sources > New Result Source.

Your result source would be something along the lines of the below

```
{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}  {searchTerms} Path:**<your site url>** owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:"**<your meta data term>**"
```

Once this is created you can create a search page by inserting the Search Web Parts (Search Box/Refiners/Results) - and changing the query in the search results webpart to the one you've created as above. This will only return items tagged with the metadata you've specified.

If you wanted multiple tags to be returned, add multiple owstaximetadata..'s to your result source and you can have the refiners webpart available to filter to the applicable one.

Comment: BoFellis. Thank you very much for the suggestion. I think that is just what I needed. First I'll gonna go through the procedure you've described above to see if I can implement it the way you've said and I'll update the status here after that.